# /dev/sda1/boot is full

Tags: kernel, boot

So my Ubuntu VM /boot is now full, I know I managed to fix this long time ago, but now what ever I do it seems to not work.

```
xxx@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filsystem                   Storlek Använt Ledigt Anv% Monterat på
udev                           2,0G      0   2,0G   0% /dev
tmpfs                          396M   6,1M   390M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root     45G   6,4G    37G  15% /
tmpfs                          2,0G      0   2,0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                          5,0M      0   5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                          2,0G      0   2,0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                      472M   469M      0 100% /boot
/dev/sdb1                      689G    77G   578G  12% /mnt/VIDEO_RECORDING
tmpfs                          396M      0   396M   0% /run/user/1000
```

I am running GNU/Linux 4.4.0-145-generic x86_64 and if I run:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

I get a lot of kernel images. So because it is full I want to try to remove with:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

and:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic
```

I get:

```
Läser paketlistor… Färdig
Bygger beroendeträd
Läser tillståndsinformation… Färdig
Du bör köra ”apt-get -f install” för att korrigera dessa.
Följande paket har beroenden som inte kan tillfredsställas:
 linux-image-generic : Beroende av: linux-image-4.4.0-150-generic men det är inte installerat eller
                                    linux-image-unsigned-4.4.0-150-generic men det är inte installerat
                       Rekommenderar: thermald men det är inte installerat
 linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-150-generic : Beroende av: linux-image-4.4.0-150-generic men det är inte installerat eller
                                                      linux-image-unsigned-4.4.0-150-generic men det är inte installerat
```

Yes I know this is Swedish, but it says that it is dependent of linux-image-4.4.0-150-generic, but it is not installed. So it suggests me to run:

```
apt-get -f install
```

Then it tries to download linux-image-4.4.0-150-generic but fails of course due lack of space. I am sure that I found some way to actually remove the kernel images manually with rm command, but I dont know where they kernel images are stored, I also tried to install byobu, to help me remove the kernel images but no space... You know..

So, is my solution now to manually remove the kernel images and if how?

Thanks!

---

```
xxx@ubuntu:/boot$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic         4.4.0-101.124                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic         4.4.0-103.126                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic         4.4.0-104.127                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-108-generic         4.4.0-108.131                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic         4.4.0-109.132                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic         4.4.0-112.135                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic         4.4.0-116.140                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic         4.4.0-119.143                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic         4.4.0-121.145                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic         4.4.0-124.148                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic         4.4.0-127.153                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic         4.4.0-128.154                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-130-generic         4.4.0-130.156                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
pi  linux-image-4.4.0-133-generic         4.4.0-133.159                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-134-generic         4.4.0-134.160                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic         4.4.0-137.163                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic         4.4.0-138.164                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic         4.4.0-139.165                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic         4.4.0-141.167                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-142-generic         4.4.0-142.168                              amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-143-generic         4.4.0-143.169                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-145-generic         4.4.0-145.171                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
iF  linux-image-4.4.0-148-generic         4.4.0-148.174                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic          4.4.0-87.110                               amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic   4.4.0-101.124                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic   4.4.0-103.126                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-104-generic   4.4.0-104.127                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic   4.4.0-108.131                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic   4.4.0-109.132                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic   4.4.0-112.135                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic   4.4.0-116.140                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic   4.4.0-119.143                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic   4.4.0-121.145                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-124-generic   4.4.0-124.148                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-127-generic   4.4.0-127.153                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-128-generic   4.4.0-128.154                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-130-generic   4.4.0-130.156                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-133-generic   4.4.0-133.159                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-134-generic   4.4.0-134.160                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-137-generic   4.4.0-137.163                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic   4.4.0-138.164                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-139-generic   4.4.0-139.165                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic   4.4.0-141.167                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-142-generic   4.4.0-142.168                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic    4.4.0-87.110                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-generic                   4.4.0.150.158                              amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

```
xxx@ubuntu:/boot$ sudo du /boot
2355    /boot/grub/fonts
2118    /boot/grub/i386-pc
253     /boot/grub/locale
7121    /boot/grub
12      /boot/lost+found
477697  /boot
```

yes I find the kernels in the /boot folder.

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` and also `du /boot`?

Comment: The kernel images, initial RAM filesystem files and other files are directly under /boot and contain the version in their name.

Comment: Use `export LANG= LC_ALL=` command to switch the current shell to English.

Comment: @jiwopene thanks for that command!

Comment: FYI, in the future, don't make a separate /boot partition and this won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Manual cleanup of `/boot`

Go to the `/boot` directory:

```
cd /boot
```

Get list of all files:

```
ls
```

Get currently running kernel version:

```
uname -r
```

Remove old kernels and initramdisks. Keep the currently running kernel and its initrd.

```
rm FILE_NAME FILE_NAME FILE_NAME
# Maybe you should use `sudo`:
sudo rm FILE_NAME FILE_NAME FILE_NAME
```

(just copy&paste file names)

## Correct cleanup method

Install `aptitude`, it is menu-based package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Run aptitude:

```
sudo aptitude
```

Find (key <kbd>/</kbd>) text `linux-image`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Press <kbd>_</kbd> (purge) or <kbd>-</kbd> (remove) for each package you want to remove. Press <kbd>g</kbd> to review the changes and then <kbd>g</kbd> again.

Comment: I removed one of all the same kernel files, then I tried your commands, didnt work, then I did apg-get install -f it started to work but failed, then I ran sudo apt autoremove, that started to remove a lot of the kernels. Then it all ended when trying to create config file for grub: removing linux-modules-4.4.0-143-generic (4.4.0-143.169) ...
Error by handeling:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-133-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Some how, it actually did work now. I am not sure what happen.. but thanks for the help!